# Dell M4600 with nVidia Quadro 2000M hangs on boot when external monitor is connected

Tags: 12.04, grub2, boot-failure, external-monitor

I have a problem with my fresh installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Dell M4600:

- nVidia quadro 2000M
- i7-2860 16GB ram
- 128GB SSD Dell/Samsung
- 750GB HDD
- IPS RGB laptop display

When it is connected via DP++ to the external Dell U2311H monitor, it hangs on boot or when wakening from suspend. If I detach the DP cable it boots normally.

I have tried all combinations that I have found, as adding to grub:

> "no splash", "boot=pci", "acpi=off", etc...

I have also changed in nVidia X settings that external monitor is the primary one and also tried to delete `monitor.xml` file. There is no change it hangs each time after grub. It starts to load daemons then both screens are blank and then completely hangs with beep sound.

What I discovered is if I detach the cable and wait for about 2 sec after grub starts booting and then physically connect DP cable while the Ubuntu is still booting everything works normally and I have a picture on my external screen while the laptop screen is off, just as I wanted.

Do you maybe know how to solve this issue? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this problem could be occurring is because the GRUB resolution is different/higher than your monitor's resolution.

You can edit your GRUB resolution in this way:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Edit line 25 and set it to 640x480px.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now restart and see if GRUB works. If it still does not show up try pressing Shift when your GRUB loads.

Comment: Thank You for the answer but this doesn't solve the issue. Actually both displays: internal and external have identical native resolutions, and they are both IPS panels from Dell ultra-professional series. The internal display has also RGB backlighting for 100% Adobe color gamut, and therefore there is no option to turn off Optimus in BIOS. What I have noticed is that even when I unplug electric cord of the external display and leave DP++ cable connected to laptop it hangs on booting just before nVidia splash screen. So the problem is with DP++ port and ubuntu. There is no problem with windows